# Incorrect Resource URL error when they're correct

Tags: drupal, resource-urls

Since the upgrade to CiviCRM 5.13.4, I have noticed a lot of websites receiving the 'Incorrect Resource URLs' even though they are correct and most of them are just the default settings.

I checked, double checked and even tripled check a good portion of these websites and deduced that they definitely have the correct URLs and everything else on the websites work as expected.

There are no other errors in any of the logs or the console and it seems this issue applies to others as well as me.

I am using Civi on Drupal 7 with PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We deduced that this error message comes from the timeout being too small in the public function  fileExists($url, $timeout = 0.50) in civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Check/Component.php.

The timeout is not long enough for all sites which is why the message pops up despite the settings being correct.

This can be resolved by either hacking the source code and increasing the timeout to something bigger, for example 1.0 or turning off the check.

You can see the gitlab issue here for more information regarding this: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1035

I believe that the Civi team are working on a fix for this as well to avoid having to hack the source code.